# Count items from a list and append them into a dictionary if the key is in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

I am trying to count items on different lists and append them in a dictionary if the items coincide with the dictionary keys but I'm struggling with the syntax and indentation, here's what I am trying to do:

```
# List of lists
lists = []
list_1 = (A,B,C)
list_2 = (A,A,B,B,C,C)
list_3 = (A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C)
lists.extend([list_1, list_2, list_2])

# Dictionary with several values
ABC_dictionary = {'A': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 5},
                  'B': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 6},
                  'c': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 7},
                  'D': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 8}}

# Get the letter count on each list
for list in lists:
    for letter, key in zip(list, ABC_dictionary.keys()): 
        if letter in ABC_dictionary.keys():
            ABC_dictionary[letter].update({'count' : 0})
            ABC_dictionary[letter]['count'] += list.count(letter)
```

However, this is actually making a mess and giving back counts that I don't quite get.

What I want the outcome to look like is:

```
#list_1
    ABC_dictionary = {'A': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 5, 'count': 1},
                      'B': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 6, 'count': 1},
                      'c': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 7, 'count': 1}.
                      'D': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 8, 'count': 0}}

#list_2
        ABC_dictionary = {'A': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 5, 'count': 2},
                          'B': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 6, 'count': 2},
                          'c': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 7, 'count': 2}.
                          'D': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 8, 'count': 0}}

#list_3
        ABC_dictionary = {'A': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 5, 'count': 3},
                          'B': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 6, 'count': 3},
                          'c': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 7, 'count': 3}.
                          'D': { 'name': 'A', 'MW': 8, 'count': 0}}
```

For each list I will then make some other calculations for instance:

```
A_weight = ABC_dictionary['A']['MW'] * ABC_dictionary['A']['count']
```

I know that for every list the count will overwrite the previous one, so I'm also wondering if there's a way of storing the values to add them to another list.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why are you zipping the keys of the dictionary? You never use `key` for anything.

Comment: Make a deep copy of the dictionary each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a deep copy of `ABC_dictionary` for each list in `lists`. Then you can put all these copies into another list.

Use `collections.Counter()` to count the repetitions in each list.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import Counter

results = []

for letters in lists:
    cur_dict = deepcopy(ABC_dictionary)
    letter_counts = Counter(letters)
    for letter, d in cur_dict.items()
        d['count'] = letter_counts.get(letter, 0)
    results.append(cur_dict)
```

Comment: Both 'deepcopy' and 'collections.Counter()' work perfectly for this job. Thanks!